# Make smaller christmas tree

Tags: java, drawing, row

So I'm beginning in the world of java programming language and I'm trying to print a christmas tree of X height. So far its working, but if for example the user input 4, it will print 4 rows + the christmas tree stump, wich mean 5. However, I would like it to be 4 INCLUDING the stump.So far I have this:

```
public class xmas {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(in);
        out.print("please enter a number: ");
        int temp = scan.nextInt();
        int x = (temp-1)*2 +1; 
        int y = x/2;  
        int z = 1;  
        for(int i=0; i<temp; i++) 
        {
            for(int j=0; j<=y; j++) 
            {
                out.print(" ");
            }
            for(int k = 0; k<z; k++)  
            {
                out.print("*");
            }
            out.println(); 
            y--;
            z+=2; 
        }
        for(int i =0; i<=x/2; i++) 
        {
            out.print(" ");
        }
        out.println("*"); 
    }
}
```

I don't know how to do that. Thanks!

Comment: It's good you've already started your preparations ;)

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: It was a joke - christmas is 3 months from now ;) How did you get the christmas tree idea? Anyway - have you considered using `temp--;` just after input `int temp = scan.nextInt();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `temp--` just after the input, like that:

```
int temp = scan.nextInt();
temp--;
```

Or decreasing your loop condition:

```
for(int i=0; i<temp-1; i++)
```

Output in both cases:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
    *
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just subtract one from the input, your christmas tree should be the right size. Here's what it would look like (using the Java style conventions):

```
public class ChristmasTree {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
        out.print("Please enter a number: ");

        int temp = scanner.nextInt() - 1; // note the `- 1`
        int x = (temp - 1) * 2 + 1;
        int y = x / 2;
        int z = 1;

        for(int i = 0; i < temp; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j <= y; j++) {
                out.print(" ");
            }

            for(int j = 0; j < z; k++) {
                out.print("*");
            }

            out.println();
            y--;
            z += 2;
        }

        for(int i =0; i<=x/2; i++) {
            out.print(" ");
        }

        out.println("*"); 
    }
}
```